# How to compare values in pandas dataframe to multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I first try to replace all the values that have "LOSE" with 0.

```
df.mask(df == 'LOSE', 0,inplace=True)
```

This works fine. I want to replace multiple values with 1.

```
df.mask(df in ['WIN','FREE','PENALTY','DRAW'],1, inplace=True)
```

This does not work:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas how to express replacing multiple values in a data-frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `isin`

```
df.mask(df.isin(['WIN','FREE','PENALTY','DRAW']),1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I am using the same query and getting an error. But when changing (inplace = False), getting the proper output. Any idea why it is happening?